# How to identify the Python kernel in which a script is running?

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have a Jupyter notebook that needs to work both on my local machine and on Google Colab. In Google Colab one has to upload the files from his local machine, so the code should include this option.

So, my problem is to check whether the script runs on Google Colab or not, and I am looking for something like:

```
if is_local:
    data = pd.read_csv('fname')
elif is_colab:                    # <-- HOW TO DO THIS???
    uploaded = files.upload()
    # here I choose fname
    data = pd.read_csv('fname')
```

Thanks!

PS - I am not sure about my terminology and would appreciate relevant editing (even to the question title).

Comment: Did you try `sys.executable`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes. It returns the path, which I think is not indicative enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many modules present only in managed Colab backends, e.g.,

```
import sys
is_colab = 'google.colab' in sys.modules
```